# Running Solr PHP cant start service

Tags: php, solr

I'm trying to start the service of Solr PHP.
I'm running `bin/solr start -f` 
but I'm getting this warning:

> Starting Solr as the root user is a security risk and not considered best practice. Exiting.
>
> Please consult the Reference Guide. To override this check, start with argument '-force'

so I added the `-force` part in `bin/solr -force start -f`.
But even then I am just getting this error:

> ERROR: start is not supported by this script

I just cant start the service.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the permissions of the solr directory to the user that will be starting solr (this should not be root)

Run `chown -R <username> <solrDir>` replacing the variables with your relevant values (for example `chown -R ghost /opt/solr`) and then start solr as that user.